# issue with share server and crypt

Tags: php, crypt

Not sure why, but on my VPS server and my local MacBook Pro. The code works
but as soon as I use it on the clients server which is shared I get this error.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: njahhya in <b>/clientdata/zeus-dynamic-1/i/n/incard.com.au/www/telesales/system/classes/core.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
0<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  task in <b>/clientdata/zeus-dynamic-1/i/n/incard.com.au/www/telesales/system/classes/core.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />
```

I know that they use a shared server, so I am not surprised but I really need it to work, is there any work around?

```
$key = "$2a$07$ikuatfc$";
$this->password = crypt($password, $key);
```

Comment: Not every server has `BLOWFISH` available. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#example-4093 (Although, I wish they did...)

Comment: Also, you should probably try a single-quoted string: `$key = '$2a$07$ikuatfc$';` so you don't get variable expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the first notice is the result of `"$2a$07$ikuatfc$"` being in double quotes. Variables in double quotes are interpolated:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo "Hello $foo"; // Hello bar
```

`"$2a$07$ikuatfc$"` is full of *possible* variable names. You should write it in single quotes to avoid variable interpolation: `'$2a$07$ikuatfc$'`.

The larger issue is likely that on your development machines you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) turned off, while on the production server error reporting is turned on by default. Turn on error reporting during development, fix all errors, turn error reporting off on production.

Comment: *interpolation*, *expansion*... Same thing.